# Trying to Figure out why I get a Print Syntax Error at Line 12

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, syntax-error

This is some really basic code I have to complete for a programming class of mine I'm stuck here I get a print syntax error although I'm about 99% sure the format to print something in python 2.7.9 is print "text here".  Please help google searches currently to no avail for me and I'm sure it's probably a quick solve.

```
minTot = 0
stepTot = 0
min = int(raw_input("Input the number of minutes (0 to exit): "))
if min == 0:
   print "No minutes input."
else:
   while min != 0:
      minTot = minTot + min
      stepRate = int(raw_input("Input the step rate: "))
      stepTot = stepTot + stepRate * min
      min = int(raw_input("Input the next number of minutes (0 to exit): ")
   print "\nTotal number of minutes:", min
   print "Total number of steps:", stepTot 
   # Average is rounded down.
   print "Average step rate per minute: ", minTot/stepTot
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Python 2.7 and not Python 3.x?

Comment: Yes I am checked in my terminal window using the command python to open the interpreter the version is 2.7.9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have unbalanced parentheses on the previous line:

```
min = int(raw_input("Input the next number of minutes (0 to exit): ")
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have gotten rid of that part of the error I'm still trying to figure out if it properly works but this has gotten me moving in the right direction I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome.  BTW, if you ask a question, you should either mark an answer as accepted or revise the question until you do get an acceptable answer.